# Trigonometric sign function

Tags: trigonometry

I am positive that this definition:
$$
\text{sgn}(x) = \frac{\text{arccot}(x) - \text{arccot}(-x)}{2|\text{arccot}(x)|}
$$

Is correct, but wolframalpha says it's not. I suspect it's because it assumes $\text{arccot}(-x) = -\text{arccot}(x)$ for all $x$, but $\text{arccot}(0) = \text{arccot}(-0) \neq 0$, right?

I sent them feedback about this already. Meanwhile, here is my proof:

Let $x < 0$. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{sgn}(x) &= \frac{\text{arccot}(x) - \text{arccot}(-x)}{2|\text{arccot}(x)|}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\text{arccot}(-|x|) - \text{arccot}(|x|)}{2|\text{arccot}(-|x|)|}\\[1em]
&= \frac{-\text{arccot}(|x|) - \text{arccot}(|x|)}{2|-\text{arccot}(|x|)|}\\[1em]
&= \frac{-2\text{arccot}(|x|)}{2\text{arccot}(|x|)}\\[1em]
&= -1\\[1em]
\end{align*}
$$

Let $x > 0$. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{sgn}(x) &= \frac{\text{arccot}(x) - \text{arccot}(-x)}{2|\text{arccot}(x)|}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\text{arccot}(|x|) - \text{arccot}(-|x|)}{2|\text{arccot}(|x|)|}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\text{arccot}(|x|) + \text{arccot}(|x|)}{2\text{arccot}(|x|)}\\[1em]
&= \frac{2\text{arccot}(|x|)}{2\text{arccot}(|x|)}\\[1em]
&= 1\\[1em]
\end{align*}
$$

Finally, let $x = 0$. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{sgn}(x) &= \frac{\text{arccot}(x) - \text{arccot}(-x)}{2|\text{arccot}(x)|}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\text{arccot}(|x|) - \text{arccot}(|x|)}{2|\text{arccot}(x)|}\\[1em]
&= \frac{0}{2|\text{arccot}(x)|}\\[1em]
&= 0\\[1em]
\end{align*}
$$

Does this check out?

**EDIT:** $\text{arccot}$ not $\arccos$, dangit.

**EDIT 2:** This is best I could do when $\text{arccot}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(x)$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{sgn}(x) &= \lim_{p\to +\infty}\Bigg[{\frac{\text{arccot}(-px) - \text{arccot}(px)}{2\text{arccot}(p|x|) + \pi}}\Bigg]
\end{align*}
$$

With the bonus that we get a smooth approximation for $p>0$, e.g. [graph for p=5000.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(arctan(5000x)+-+arctan(-5000x))%2F(2(pi+-+arctan(5000%7Cx%7C))),+plot+-15+%3C+x+%3C+15)

Apparently that's a sigmoid function. Maybe I will ask another question about it!

Comment: Think about the domains of the functions involved.  What is the domain of $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$?  What is the domain of $\arccos x$?

Comment: I did a silly. Give me a sec.

Comment: If you write ArcCot[x]-ArcCot[-x]/.x->0, Mathematica will simplify the expression prior to the substitution, and indeed it will simplify to 2 ArcCot[x]. It does this in many situations, not just this one.

Comment: But that's incorrect, isn't it? Shouldn't it be considered a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the underlying issue is that Wolfram Alpha defines $\operatorname{arccot} x$ as $\arctan 1/x$ and subsequently stumbles a bit with the discontinuity that creates at $x=0$  According to Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) $\operatorname{arccot} x$ should have range $(0,\pi)$, but that would create a problem for you.  Without having given it too much thought, I think I would prefer my $\operatorname{arccot}$ to be continuous at $x=0$, thus $\operatorname{arccot} x = \pi/2 - \arctan x$

Comment: That sounds reasonable! Julia seems to use mathematica's definition of arccot, but my sign function works there... Well, it won't hurt to have another sign for the continuous arccot, I am sure I can do something with it. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

But $\arccos(-x)=\pi-\arccos(x)$

Comment: I meant arccot. Dang. Sorry about that.